# Periodic snapshot fact table with large dimensions

Tags: data-warehouse, snapshot, dimensional-modeling

I have been asked to model a star diagram.
I have 3 dimensions:

1. Date (day,month, year, week, quarter, ...)
2. place (500 distinct values)
3. Product (80k different products)

The main question is how many items (products) are stored at the end of a day in every place.

After some study-time with regards to dimensional modeling. I think I should implement a **Periodic snapshot table**. However reading trough the Kimball Docs, I noticed that a periodic snapshot demands an entry for every combination of the dimensions. This means I should add **40M** rows every day (80k*500).
Knowing that the products are (real) slow movers and that many places store **zero** products during long periods, this sounds like an extreme overkill.
FYI the transactions in the source DB are 150k rows after three years.

So should I really add 40M rows every day, or could I just add the non-empty stores with their products specified? Also if for whatever reason one day all stores are empty, should I make an entry for that day (with dimensions N/A for store and product)?

Comment: You should always go with the lowest grain, since you don't know the questions which will be asked later. If you define a rule to handle empty stores with "N/A", you can do that - or maybe ask the business how they would identify this case and model after that.

Comment: I agree with the lowest grain, but I don't want to make it transactional, cause this would make my query more complex (the goal is to have a graph of last ten days for each store, and with transactional grain, there will be a lot of date's not filled in)

Comment: I would always go with a little more complex query and good indices as to let go the lowest granularity.

Comment: So stating the grain as location of (active) products per store at end of day, seems correct. Does this mean that I should add a row per product,store combination every day? My first guess is no

Comment: Product (amount), Store, Day. Why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You modeled correctly. It depends from the specifications, but normally you store only the products that are present in a location (you do not store zeroes), which could yield a number substantially lower than the maximum 80k.

If you want to further reduce your numbers, you could store the last N days and then start to move data in a "cold" table. You store (say) last 10 day snapshot, then only monthly snapshots in the main "hot" Fact Table.

Do not exclude the possibility to calculate the snapshot on the fly in report system, depending on your environment it could be easy (in MDX or DAX for example it is). Mixed solutions are also possible (i.e only the last month calculated on the fly).